# How to get android wifi scanresult.timestamp in EPOCH time

Tags: android, timestamp, android-wifi

How can I get the time for scanresult.timestamp in EPOCH time? It looks like it is returning SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanResultTimestampInMillisSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (scanResult.timestamp / 1000)
```

Comment: I found I had to use the following: 

`long rxTimestampMillis =  System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + scanResult.getTimestampNanos() / 1000000;`

Comment: It looks like the getTimestampNanos() method is for *bluetooth* scanresults, not wifi: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html

Comment: @NeilS: why are you dividing the timestamp by 1000? It should already be milliseconds according to the docs..? NVM I read milliseconds but it says milliseconds ... :S

Comment: I use this to receive the timestamp of the wifi : `long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - scanning.timestamp, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);`  However, I only received the scanning for one time. I'm still have difficulty for continuous WiFi scan

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me was

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - 
    (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (scanResultTimestamp / 1000))
```